# $Z_{2}$- graded structures for $C_{red} ^{*} (F_{2})$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, graded-banach-algebras

Let $F_{2}$ be the free group with two generators.

Then $F_{2}=\{\text{odd words}\}\sqcup\{\text{even words}\}$. This gives us a $Z_{2}$ graded structure for $C^{*}_{red} (F_{2})$, in a natural way.

My question:

> Is there another $Z_{2}$ graded structure for $C^{*}_{red} (F_{2})$  which is not graded isomorphic to the above $Z_{2}$- graded structure?

Please consider the same question for $C^{*}_{red} (F_{1}) \sim C(\mathbb{S}^{1})$.

Namely: is there a $Z_{2}$ graded structure for $C(\mathbb{S}^{1})$ which is  not graded isomorphism to the standard grading structure(decomposition to even and odd continuous functions)?

Comment: Have you considered the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading associated with the involutive automorphism of $F_2$ obtained by flipping the generators?

Comment: For $C(S^1)$, you also have the grading associated to the automorphism $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ of $S^1$ (viewed as the group of complex numbers of modulus one). The sub-algebra of elements of degree 0, is isomorphic to $C[-1,1]$, proving that this grading is not isomorphic to the one by even/odd functions (which is associated to $z\mapsto -z$).

Comment: @AlainValette  Thank you very much for your comments. I consider the grading structure for $C^{*}_{red}( F_{2})= A_{0} \oplus A_{1}$ where $A_{0}$ is the banach space generated by even words and $A_{1}, with odd words.

Comment: In particular, does the graded structure which you mentioned is graded isomorphic to this structure which I mentioned?

Comment: considering these two graded structures, how can we compare the k theory of corresponding trivial homo genus algebras?(zeo degree algebras)?

Comment: What about placing the whole algebra in degree $0$?

Comment: @Fernando In this question I only consider nontrivial grading.

Comment: Ah! You didn't specify! ;-)

Comment: Is the tag 'graded-banach-algebras' not overly specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is well-known that $K_1(C^*_{\rm red}(F_2))={\mathbb Z^2}$ with generators given by $[u]$ and $[v]$, where $F_2=\langle u,v\rangle$.

Now, the automorphism of order two associated with the even-odd grading is multiplying each generator by $-1$, which is homotopic to the multiplication by $1$. Hence it is trivial on $K_1$.

On the other side, the automorphism of order two that comes mapping $u$ to $v$ and $v$ to $u$ gives rise to a non-trivial action on $K_1$. Thus, the two automorphisms of order two cannot be conjugate - and hence the associated graded algebras cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I think that I can get the answer to my question from first version of your answer: two "Flipping" and "antipodal" automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ are not conjugate. I think in the revised version, some thing is missing:the two C* automorphisms are not homotopic because their induced K group automorphism are not equal. Thanks again for your help on my question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the first version contained a mistake and the current version is correct.

Comment: what is the homotopy which you mentioned in the current version?

Comment: for the homotopy, are you considering a curve in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\})$ which connect 1 to -1?

Comment: Yes, exactly, along the unit circle.