# Connected component of the identity in graded Banach algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, graded-banach-algebras

I search  for  a **noncommutative**  idempotent-less Banach algebra $A$ which is graded by a finite abelian group $G$ such that a nontrivial homogenous element lies in the same connected component as $1_{A}$ (in the  space of invertible elements).

*Motivation: This situation is impossible for commutative idempotent-less Banach algebras.*

By a *nontrivial homogenous element*, I mean the following:

Assume $A=\oplus_{g\in G}  A_{g}$. A nontrivial homogenous element is an element of $A_{g}$ for some $g\neq e$.

By *idempotent-less* I mean: $A$ has no nontrivial idempotent.

In  particular, can one obtain an example with $A=C^{*}_{red}(F_{2})$ which is graded by each of the two $Z_{2}$-graded structures discussed in the following post?:

[$Z_{2}$- graded structures for $C_{red} ^{*} (F_{2})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152660/z-2-graded-structures-for-c-red-f-2)